# session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in <b>/storage/ssd4/417/11749417/public_html/login.php

Tags: php, hosting

tengo un proyecto web, en localhost funciona muy bien lo subí a un hosting gratuito para realizar pruebas al subirlo se ve mi index y luego el login pero al poner mis credenciales no pasa de esa pagina es cuando se genera el error:

```
session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in <b>/storage/ssd4/417/11749417/public_html/login.php
```

este es mi código donde dice que esta el error:

```
<?php session_start();
require 'admin/config.php';
require 'functions.php';
$errores = '';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {
  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  //sirve para encriptar la contraseña en la base de datos no funciona a la hora de extraerlos y validarlos para accesar despues del login
  //$password = hash('sha512', $password);
  $conexion = conexion($bd_config);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password');
  $statement->execute([
    ':usuario' => $usuario,
    ':password' => $password
  ]);
  $resultado = $statement->fetch();
  if ($resultado !== false) 
  {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: '.RUTA.'validar.php');
  } 
  else 
  {
    $errores .= '<li class="error">Tu usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectos</li>';
  }
}
require 'views/login.views.php';
?>
```

e leído que por espacios que se generan antes de las etiquetas de `<?php` y de hecho este archivo llamado `login.php` si tiene un espacio antes de la etiqueta `<?php` pero al corregirlo sale un nuevo error que es el siguiente:

```
session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /storage/ssd4/417/11749417/tmp) in
```

no encuentro solución a esto ya que en mi `localhost` funcionaba bien, mis credenciales de la base de datos las tengo bien definidas en este archivo llamado `config.php`:

```
<?php
define('RUTA', 'https://controlflotilla.000webhostapp.com');
$bd_config=[
'db_name'=>'xxx',
'user'=>'xxx',
'pass'=>'xxx'
];
?>
```

estos son los permisos que tiene la carpeta tmp
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código con el que hago el formulario del login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>    
     <!--jquery librerias-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <!--boostrap librerias-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap_4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap_4.3.1/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap_4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

    <!--librerias para crear animaciones-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="wowjs/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">new WOW().init();</script> 

    <!--librerias para crear efecto hover-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Hover/css/hover-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">   
</head>
<body class="bg-image">
<div class="container">
 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">

    <div class="input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-user-o icons" aria-hidden="false"></i>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <i class="fa fa-lock icons" aria-hidden="false"></i>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control" required>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <?php if (!empty($errores)): ?>
          <?php echo $errores ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
<div class="input-group">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-flat-green">Ingresar</button>   
</div>
<div class="input-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark hvr-float" onclick="location.href='index.html'">
 Inicio</button>
 </div> 
    <!--<a href="<?php //echo RUTA.'registro.php' ?>" class="login-link">¿No tienes cuenta?</a>-->
</form>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<div class="textologin">
<h1 id="titulologin" class="wow bounceInDown">Una Solucion Fluida Para Tu Proyecto</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira la configuración de las sesiones de PHP, en el archivo `php.ini`. Aségurate de que tienes acceso de lectura y escritura a `/storage/ssd4/417/11749417/tmp`.

Comment: deja lo reviso en el archivo php.ini en la base de datos verdad ?

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, no sé si 000webhost te da acceso al `php.ini` :/

Comment: que es lo que se debe editar de la carpeta tmp ?? edite mi pregunta y puse unas imágenes no se si ahí es donde me indicas

Comment: Ponle permisos 777, activale las tres casillas a 'others'

Comment: ya lo hice y aun así me sigue marcando los mismos errores le di todos los permisos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Éste error quiere decir que ya se hizo algún `echo` o en el inicio del script hay un espacio en blanco.

Por lo general esto ocurre cuando tienes un espacio o texto antes de `<?php`, por favor asegurate que no tengas un espacio en blanco y no tengas output antes del `session_start`.

EDIT:

Veo el segúndo error, debes darle permisos de lectura/escritura a la carpeta `/storage/ssd4/417/11749417/tmp`, en caso de no poder cambiar los permisos de esa carpeta puedes solucionar cambiando la ruta de la carpeta donde se almacenaran las sesiones con la siguiente linea:

```
session_save_path('/tu/ruta/no/publica/sessions');
```

Saludos.

Comment: si tengo un espacio en en la pagina login.php al iniciar la etiqueta <?php lo quito y aparece esto : session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /storage/ssd4/417/11749417/tmp) in

Comment: Acabo de ver el error, es muy probable que necesites darle permisos de lectura/escritura a la carpeta  /storage/ssd4/417/11749417/tmp

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta dando una posible solución.}

Comment: que es lo que se debe editar de la carpeta tmp ?? edite mi pregunta y puse unas imágenes no se si ahí es donde me indicas